# Updating Textview in an Activity with Local Service

Tags: android, service, textview

I have an Activity with R.id.eventDistance and R.id.eventTime to display the distance & travel time based on current location. I calculate these values every 30 seconds using my Location Service class.

My question is: how do I update the TextView in Activity? I've tried looking up the question and found some possible solutions such as using a BroadcastReceiver and call TextView.setText() in the onReceive() method. I'm not sure how this is done. Am I supposed to pass in the Activity class like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
   }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do after that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

please see this flow.

1.in your LocationService class when you want to update UI. in your case it should be called every 30 seconds.

```
Intent i = new Intent("LOCATION_UPDATED");
i.putExtra("<Key>","text");

sendBroadcast(i);
```

2.in your UI (HomeActivity) class

in onCreate()

```
registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("LOCATION_UPDATED"));
```

in class

```
private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TextView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("<KEY>"))

    }
};
```

in onDestroy()

```
unregisterReceiver(uiUpdated);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I changed your code
`TextView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("<KEY>"))` to what works with my code. Something like:
`distanceTextView.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("distance")).`. But it's not working. The text view doesn't change. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The only thing that's different from your code is I use bundle instead of putExtra.
`Bundle extras = i.getExtras();`
`extras.putString("distance", distance);`
`extras.putString("duration", duration);`
Does that affect anything?

Comment: I put a Log.d inside BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() and that line is never printed...

Comment: `Illegal modifier for parameter uiUpdated; only final is permitted` I Removed private modifier

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your Activity to your service so that they can directly communicate and message pass.

### Ref

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html